# Change domain URL from https to http in google search results

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, search-engine

I have changed my domain name. I updated my 'new' domain to point to my server and I configured my 'old' domain and sub-domains to 301 forward to the 'new' one. All is working well beside when running query in google.
 I'm using Tomcat7 as my webserver and my server is running on AWS instance
Since my website use SSL in google search results there is https URL version of my 'old' URL and since 301 forward is not working to https traffic my users are getting into `'Page not available' ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED instead to my 'new' domain`.
 
I sent request 1 day ago to google via webmaster tools of change of Address notice between my 'old' and 'new' domains but still there is no change in the google search results.
 Anyhow i dont know if that will help.
Anything else i can do, how can i tell google to use my http version and not https?
 
Is there anyway to workaround the problem ?

Comment: Can you show your current rules?

Comment: What kind of rules you are referring?

Comment: You need to get the 301 redirects working.

Comment: Where is 301 forwarding happening at present?

Comment: The 301 forward is defined in goDaddy. its working well when I enter the old domain with http and its not working with https. It is not so critical. the main problem that google gives in the search result the https url which lead to page not available